# New relation symbol

Tags: symbols, relation-symbols

I am defining a new relation in one of my new papers. I want to use the following symbol, because it conveys the meaning of my relation. Is there such a symbol in LaTex ? It is very similar to \leq and \preceq. If not, is there a way to add new symbols by hacking the back-end of LaTeX.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)?

Comment: Yes. I tried Detexify. No Luck.

Comment: According to [Every symbol defined by unicode-math](http://meeting.contextgarden.net/2011/talks/day3_05_ulrik_opentype/Samples/unimath-symbols.pdf), there is no such a symbol, although some are really close to what you have in mind.

Comment: I'm now mildly curious about this relation. When you publish the paper, if you have put an electronic pre-print somewhere, please link to it here for us to read.

Comment: I expected this curiosity :) I have been wondering how to draw this symbol for quite some time. Thanks to all the excellent answers, now I know. This symbol makes a lot of justice to my paper. I will post a link to my paper as soon as it is ready.

Comment: I used this symbol in my paper http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5170

Answer (score 40):

Here's an attempt (better than the first one).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\xle}{%
  \mathrel{\vphantom{\le}%
    \smash{\vcenter{\hbox{\oalign{%
      \noalign{\kern.2ex}
      \rotatebox[origin=l]{25}{$\scriptstyle\to$}\cr
      \noalign{\kern-.95ex}
      \kern-.03em
      \rotatebox[origin=l]{-25}{$\scriptstyle\to$}\cr
      \noalign{\kern.35ex}
      \smash{$-$}\cr
    }}}}%
  }
}

\begin{document}
\fbox{$A\xle B$}\fbox{$A \le C$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 28):

You can draw it in TikZ and play with its shape:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\def\newrel{%
    \ensuremath{%
        \mathrel{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-0.8ex]
                \draw [line width=0.06ex, line join=round, stealth'-stealth']
                    (1.5ex,0.67ex) -- (0, 0) -- (1.5ex, -0.67ex);
                \draw [line width=0.06ex, line cap=round]
                    (0.03ex, -1ex) -- (1.47ex, -1ex);
            \end{tikzpicture}%
        }%
    }%
}

\begin{document}

normal\newrel text, $math \newrel mode$

\Large Large\newrel text, $math \newrel mode$

\end{document}
```

[image: compiled code]

Comment: If you put the symbol in `\mathrel` (math mode), then you automatically get proper math spacing for a relational symbol.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, thank you for the comment. I've updated the code. Indeed, it's much simpler now.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a start:

```
\newcommand\ltarreq{\mathrel{\raise 2pt\rlap{\rotatebox{20}{$\scriptstyle\rightarrow$}}%
    \raise 2.5pt\rlap{\rotatebox{-20}{$\scriptstyle\rightarrow$}}%
    \lower 2pt\hbox{$-$}}}
```

It's a bit ugly, but it shows you how to do what you want (almost).