# Designing a new tuple of Algebra Operators

Tags: math-mode, symbols, math-operators, logic, amssymb

It's neccessary to have at least ***two*** extra tuples of Albera Operators.

A **minimal** tuple is a triple **(to_be_subset_eq, meet_operator, join_operator)**.

There are some ideas how to make 2 extra tupes. However I need help with their implementation. For examples, as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{soul}
\setul{1pt}{0.5pt} %depth, thikness

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\renewcommand{\ULthickness}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\ULdepth}{1pt}

\usepackage{accents}

\def\uSubsetOne{\mbox{\bfseries\b{$\Subset$}}}
\def\uSubsetTwo{\mbox{\ul{$\Subset$}}} %soul package
\def\uSubsetThree{\mbox{\uline{$\Subset$}}} %ulem pakcage
\newcommand{\uSubsetFour}[1]{\underline{#1\mkern-4mu}\mkern4mu } %\underline hacking
```

[the \underline hacking is from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49324/decrease-length-of-underline-in-math)

```
\def\uSubsetFive{\mathbf{\underaccent{\bar}{\Subset}}} %accent package

\begin{document}

1. In the First triple  $(\sqsubseteq,\sqcap,\sqcup)$ we need to increase the thickness.

2. Possible variants of $\Subset$ upgrading.

2.1. $(\uSubsetOne,\Cap,\Cup)$ --- the line should be at the right corner.

2.2. $(\uSubsetTwo,\Cap,\Cup)$ ---  the width of the line is too large, soul package. 

2.3. $(\uSubsetThree,\Cap,\Cup)$ ---  the width of the line is too large, ulem package.

2.4. $(\uSubsetFour{\Subset},\Cap,\Cup)$ --- lack of thickness, problems with depth and positioning, width is too large. 

2.5. $(\uSubsetFive,\Cap,\Cup)$ --- the line should be at the right corner, accents package.

\end{document}
```

The result of compilation:
[image: The result of compilation]

Here are some useful links:
[to design a New Large Math Symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2528/new-large-math-symbol)

[to design a New Arrow-like relation symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109293/new-relation-symbol) - this variant is aslo applicable in case of implementing `\multimapdot` instead of an arrow in a triple `(\sqsubseteq,\sqcap,\sqcup)`.

[to design a New fuzzy logic symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151816/fuzzy-logic-operator-symbols)

[to design a New Box-like symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122230/defining-operator-symbols)

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: The `\stackinset` macro of the `stackengine` package is very good at overlaying glyphs, if you need to tailor the appearance of your new operators.  And insets can be nested.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139355/looking-for-bigcap-or-bigdoublecap/139365#139365, for example, or just do a search for `\stackinset`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Note: It's very nice that [`tabstackengine`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabstackengine) has found it's way to CTAN. `:)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg  Thanks.  I will be releasing an update soon to fix two of the bugs noted in the documentation.  But I just wanted to get the package out the door, since I had been sitting on it so long.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thank you. The example works great. One of the best parameters are `\stackunder[0.8pt]{$\Subset$}{\rule{1.4ex}{.3pt}}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this more what you are looking for?  I have used the `stackengine` package for setting things vertically relative.  The thicker square operators were created by laying two copies in close proximity (.2pt vertical and horizontal offset).  The underlined subset placed a `\rule` under the `\Subset`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\def\Sqsubseteq{\def\stacktype{L}\mathrel{\stackon[.2pt]{\sqsubseteq}{\kern.2pt\sqsubseteq}}}
\def\Sqcap{\def\stacktype{L}\mathrel{\stackon[.2pt]{\sqcap}{\kern.2pt\sqcap}}}
\def\Sqcup{\def\stacktype{L}\mathrel{\stackon[.2pt]{\sqcup}{\kern.2pt\sqcup}}}
\def\uSubset{\mathrel{\stackunder[1pt]{\Subset}{\rule{1.35ex}{.45pt}}}}
\begin{document}
1. In the First triple  $(\sqsubseteq,\sqcap,\sqcup)$ we need to increase the thickness.\par
1. Try $(\Sqsubseteq,\Sqcap,\Sqcup)$\par
2. Possible variants of $\Subset$ upgrading.\par
Try $(\uSubset,\Cap,\Cup)$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to improve the situation with the code? I've got some errors just after its extention by the line `\stackunder[0.8pt]{$\Subset$}{\rule{1.4ex}{.3pt}}`, probably because of `\stackMath`.

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko Are you using `stackengine` for anything else in your document, or just this?  One can omit the `\stackMath` if one is willing to enclose the `\stackon` arguments in `$` delimiters.  And what do you mean by "extention"?  Further, this solution will not, without changes, translate to smaller sizes like `\scriptstyle`, if that is an issue.

Comment: Yes. I've tried to add the commands `\stackunder[0.8pt]{$\Subset$}{\rule{1.4ex}{.3pt}}` and `\stackengine{\Lstackgap}{A}{BC}{O}{r}{F}{\useanchorwidth}{L}` after `$(\uSubset,\Cap,\Cup)$`. Commenting of `\stackMath` does not help.

Comment: @VladimirParkhomenko  If I take my MWE from above (with the `\stackMath` in place), and add these two lines before the end: `\stackunder[0.8pt]{\Subset}{\rule{1.4ex}{.3pt}} and 
\stackengine{\Lstackgap}{A}{BC}{O}{r}{F}{\useanchorwidth}{L}`, it compiles just fine.  I had to remove the `$` signs from what you had placed in your comment, since `\stackMath` will place those dollar signs there for you..

Answer (score 7):

I'm fond of `\ooalign`, as everybody knows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,bm}
\newcommand{\Subseteq}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \vphantom{\subseteq}%
    \smash{\vcenter{\doSubseteq}}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\doSubseteq}{%
  \hbox{\ooalign{%
    \noalign{\kern.5ex}
    $\Subset$\cr
    \noalign{\kern1.1ex}
    \smash{$-$}\cr
  }}%
}
\newcommand{\bsqsubseteq}{\bm{\sqsubseteq}}
\newcommand{\bsqcup}{\bm{\sqcup}}
\newcommand{\bsqcap}{\bm{\sqcap}}

\begin{document}

\fboxsep=0pt\fboxrule=0.1pt
\fbox{$\subseteq\Subseteq\subset\Subset$} % just to show the relative shapes

$(\subseteq,\cap,\cup)$

$(\Subseteq,\Cap,\Cup)$

$(\sqsubseteq,\sqcap,\sqcup)$

$(\bsqsubseteq,\bsqcap,\bsqcup)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The idea to use `\bm` is very appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

here's a possibility.  admittedly, it will work only with computer modern and `amsfonts`, and i haven't tested it except at "normal" (text and display style) size.

[image: output of example code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\newcommand{\Subseteq}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \lower.32ex\hbox{$
    \begin{matrix}
      \Subset\\[-1.78ex] \smash{-}
    \end{matrix}$}
  }}

\begin{document}

Compare: \quad $\subseteq \Subseteq$

Triple $\Subset$:\quad $\Subseteq,\Cap,\Cup$

\end{document}
```